# Event listener with parameters and innerHTML only works once

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, innerhtml

I have a script that adds some text to page, like so:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="image" id="alertMeID" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0" //src="http://i55.tinypic.com/2nly5wz.gif" ///>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="image" id="alertMeID2" style="position:fixed;top:100;left:100" //src="http://i55.tinypic.com/2nly5wz.gif" />';
document.getElementById('alertMeID').addEventListener('click', function(){do_this("some text")}, false);
document.getElementById('alertMeID2').addEventListener('click', function(){do_this("another text")}, false);

function do_this(sendingParameter){document.body.innerHTML += sendingParameter;}
```

The first time I click on one of the images it works properly.  But, if I click a second time, it doesn't work at all.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

When you use `innerHTML` the element's content gets reparsed.  The elements are removed and recreated, which in turn removes the event handler.  Much better would be to use DOM manipulation.

```
function do_this(sendingParameter){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sendingParameter));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mdtSY/

Comment: +1, but text nodes shouldn't be added directly to the body, they should be in a block element. But I doubt any browswer is going to complain about that.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at: insertAdjacentHTML

It states at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

> insertAdjacentHTML() parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position. It does not reparse the element it is being used on and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside that element. This avoids the extra step of serialization, making it much faster than direct innerHTML manipulation.